# OCS2007 R2 - Why have Multiple Pools

Tags: windows-server-2008, ms-office-communicator

So I'm running OCS 2007 R2 Enterprise.  We currently have one pool with one server in it.  When we brought out a consultant he was emphatic that we needed a director server.  So we brought it up but didn't have time to fully intigrate it to the envrioment.  He left and now that I have time to research the stuff I think I he's wrong.

My understanding is that a director routes between multiple pools, so if a user logs in and is on pool A, he'll go to pool A and not pool B.  To scale a pool incase of performance issues a hardware loadbalancer is required(which is what we were concerned about).

So if my above understanding is correct, why have multiple pools?  Is there somewhere that cleanly explains this?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether or not you need to deploy a director typically depends on how many users your pool is hosting. It also depends on how many of your users utilize remote access and how many of your users federate with other enterprises.

Since you have only one pool with one server in it, you don't need a director for local users.

The primary job of a director in your topology would be authentication of traffic coming from outside the enterprise. For example, if somebody attacks your edge server with thousands of bogus user login attempts, the director will fend them off without impacting your local enterprise users.